IONOS ftp-login via PHP not working but the connection via FTP client like filezilla works?
We receive the message on all possible systems where we have stored FTP login data (shopify, xentral etc.):
Upload failed: FTP Error: 530 Login incorrect.
The access data is correct because the connection via FTP client like filezilla works.
This Script:
$ftp = ftp_ssl_connect(FTP_HOST);
//$ftp = ftp_connect(FTP_HOST);

if (false === $ftp) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
}

$login_result = ftp_login($ftp, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);

if (true === $login_result) {
    echo "login ok<br>";
} else {
    throw new Exception('Unable to log in ' . __LINE__);
}

$cd = ftp_pwd($ftp);

echo $cd . "<br>";

ftp_close($ftp);

works well with all ftp access data from various test servers except IONOS access data.
the very poor IONOS support (call center) can do nothing.
Is anyone aware of anything that IONOS has changed?

What are your specific connection settings in FileZilla?

The error message strangely does not match anything in your code.

Yes, they stopped supporting unencrypted ftp on August 31, 2024.
Yes, their customer support is terrible and can do nothing, customer since 2007. Now I'm looking elsewhere, fed up with them over the years.

But the OP code is trying to connect with encrypted FTP.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
